# I can not fetch data from useSession() in nextauth which i insert manually

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js13, next-auth

api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      id: "google",
      clientId:
        "872222598159-8dvmageln5ijiugr101pcq4n6rs4mmvf.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      clientSecret: "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",
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      // Adding the token to the session object so it's available in the client
      if (token) {
        session.user.idToken = token.idToken;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token!;
        token.idToken = account.id_token!;
      }

      return token;
    },
  },
  debug: true,
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Here i manually insert idToken into the session but when i fetch the idToken by the help of useSession() it will throw me the error.

button.tsx file :

```
"use client";

import { signIn, signOut, useSession, getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { graphqlClient } from "../clients/api";
import { verifyUserGoogleTokenQuery } from "../graphql/query/user";

interface sessionTypes {
  name: string | null | undefined;
  email: string | null | undefined;
  image: string | null | undefined;
  idToken: string | null | undefined;
}

export const LoginButton = () => {
  const { data } = useSession();
  console.log("Session data:------------------> ", data);

  const handleSignin = async() => {
    await signIn();
    const {verifyGoogleToken} = await graphqlClient.request(verifyUserGoogleTokenQuery, {token: data?.user?.idToken})
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleSignin} className="text-white font-bold">
      Sign in
    </button>
  );
};
```

In the button.tsx file i can not fetch the idToken. It throw me this error:

"Property 'idToken' does not exist on type '{ name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }'."

but when i log the session data idToken is present. Session data:------------------> in console :

```
Session data:------------------> 
expires: "2023-11-18T18:05:27.592Z"
user:
  email: "santisingha191@gmail.com"
  idToken: 
"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdkMzM0NDk3NTA2YWNiNzRjZGVlZGFhNjYxODRkMTU1NDdmODM2OTMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.XZrkiZzAOVhfs515cEz18Rfi-OqiRXw62Dd82MGhsClR9U76GZBeyZ8diQhyaJl95TEfZfSOCe9fgop5GgN071PwsUhhcMHp1Ff_5euY74iMKLtz_520Xx6hC4aaZ56VtqZ0Lowz8yAaLh1ybQ88qRxLzK5vky_OJVIDFvPC32-hSqDjJ_SmaI4G7DPXWL0oVUyS7uucgU_YQKY_h6lGc38NG4M2DEQIvT1rSpyNhfLxq1psXAvfRRhqrs8hOdBBBkyfvjbOtL4CVMnOIgxrpM7rcez6Q-D7MMsUtu_hnhuouefLI_KAcUFD8JnDFTw3uwW_4bk5KBGiNE4otf6qxw"
image: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKFh1GF2dCA8jSNJbbU7Sg130anxLeLTappUhHtxpu-=s96-c"
name: "SANTI SINGHA"
```

I can not understand the problem.